# Opening a serial port works with hardcoded string but not ls(path)

Tags: matlab, serial-port

This works:

`fopen(serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1451'))`

This does not:

`fopen(serial(ls('/dev/tty.usb*')))`

Even though `ls('/dev/tty.usb*')` returns this:

```
ans =

/dev/tty.usbmodem1451
```

So why does it work for a hardcoded string but not the result of `ls`?

Even more perplexing to me is the error when I try it with `ls`, which seems to claim that the serial port is *both available and not available*:

```
Error using serial/fopen (line 72)
Open failed: Port: /dev/tty.usbmodem1451
 is not available. Available ports: /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port,
 /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port, /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem, /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem
 /dev/tty.usbmodem1451, /dev/cu.usbmodem1451.
Use INSTRFIND to determine if other instrument objects are connected to the
requested device.
```

Comment: `ls` returns a list of elements. It just so happens that the list is 1 element in your case. Serial only takes a single string.

Comment: And by "list of elements", Eugene actually means *cell array*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered how to get the result of `ls` as a string, which should work as long as there is only one device listed:

```
s = serial(strcat(ls('/dev/tty.usb*')))
fopen(s)
```